# 17.10 on Wayland not available

Tags: gnome, xorg, wayland

I have been running 17.04 using Gnome on Wayland for several months now without any problems. When I answered yes to the update to 17.10 on Wayland nothing happened (a warning about not being able to open an X window appeared when I used the terminal) so I updated to 17.10 on Gnome on Xorg instead.

After the update I have three choices in the boot screen:

```
Gnome,
Gnome unter Xorg,
Gnome unter Xorg (this appears twice),
Ubuntu,
Ubuntu on Xorg,
Ubuntu on Xorg (again this appears twice),  
Unity
```

All three versions boot up OK with some minor differences in the two Xorg desktops and the Unity is my old Unity desktop. If I launch the Gnome or Ubuntu desktop and run "echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE" it simply answers "X11" as you would expect.

My question is why would 17.04 run perfectly well on Wayland but not 17.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem seems to have fixed itself. I switched from gdm to lightdm and then back again and then rebooted the computer. The boot took ages but when it was finished there was a new login screen with the choice of Gnome, Gnome on Xorg, Ubuntu, Ubuntu on Xorg. I chose "Gnome" and low and behold running "echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE" answers "Wayland".